# Some of products are giving error not found cms page in magento 2 multistore website

Tags: magento2, multistore, products

I have a website in Magento 2 with multistore functionality with Italian and English store. The same products are working fine in the english store but in the Italian store giving an error: There was no 404 CMS page configured or found.
Ursl of both stores :

English: https://europe.ibamboli.store/ibambolicolors

Italian: https://www.ibamboli.store/ibambolicolors

Everything was working fine I don,t know what is an issue with multistore or its product URLs.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are to trying with wrong Url path at Italian that why you getting the 404 page for https://www.ibamboli.store/ibambolicolors.

the product is exiting also at: `https://www.ibamboli.store`

**Check the Url:**

> https://www.ibamboli.store/catalog/product/view/id/8

this is row Product Url for Product.

I guess the SEO Url is different at  **Italian store**

Find the right SEO URL from  Admin Panel , then go to `Marketing>SEO&Search>URL Rewrites.`

Comment: Thanks for your good answer but before it was working with the same URL and now its giving problem ..so what is this issue can you help me, please

Comment: I guess that it should issue with URL key is changed.

Comment: okay so, can I revert it to the old URLs ?

Comment: Possible. if you changes URL key and also remove the current existing record of that products  from url_rewrite

Comment: can you let me know how you find out the target URL without admin

Comment: Goto `Admin Panel` , then go to `Marketing>SEO&Search>URL Rewrites` and here you find product Url